# How to get value of form filed card_number to pass to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

How would I get the value of card_number to pass to the controller?
Every time I submit the form I get NULL in the form variable

View:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.card_number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "card_number" } })

<script>
var frm = $('#formFilter');
    function OnFormSubmit() {
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),

                data: function (frm) {

                    frm.card_number = $('#card_number').val();

                },

                success: function (data) {

                    $("#dataResult").html(data);
                    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                        "dom": 'lifrtp'

                    });
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

controller:

```
 private List<testtest> GetListChanges(Report changeControl)
        {
          ...logic here....

            return returnListhere;
        }
```

Comment: serialize the form and send that as ajax `data` ?

Comment: @Shyju I know I can do this data: frm.serialize(), but I would like to do this another way.

Comment: How does your `Report` class looks like ? Are you getting `null` now ?

Comment: @Shyju no, if i use the "data: frm.serialize()," I am able to get the values

Answer (score 0):

The `data` property of the $.ajax method options should be an object or string which represents your data. With your current code you are setting a `function` to that.

```
var d = {
            card_number:  "1234",
            someOtherPropertyNameOfReport: "Hello"
        };

$.ajax({
          type: frm.attr('method'),
          url: frm.attr('action'),
          data: JSON.stringify(d),
          contentType:"application/json",
          success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
          }
 });
```

Now jquery will send the request with `Content-Type` request header value set to `application/json` and request data (the stringified version of your JavaScript object) in the request body and model binder will be able to properly read and map it to your view model, assuming the structure of the view model matches with your JavaScript object structure.

As suggested in the comment, try to use `serialize()` method. It is simply and you do not need to manually build the object.

Also your controller action method should be `public`